# VBA Testing Desktop Composition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few excel projects which utilize userforms. Those userforms have some code which uses Windows API calls to modify their style. An example of this can be found here:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DwmSetWindowAttribute Lib "dwmapi" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal attr As Integer, ByRef attrValue As Integer, ByVal attrSize As Integer) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea Lib "dwmapi" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByRef NEWMARGINS As MARGINS) As Long
Private UFSHADOW As Long
Private Type MARGINS
    leftWidth As Long
    rightWidth As Long
    topHeight As Long
    bottomHeight As Long
End Type

Sub all_userForms_AddShadow(frm As Object)
'Sub adds a shadow

Dim MARGINS As MARGINS

UFSHADOW = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", vbNullString) 'Create a new Window

DwmSetWindowAttribute UFSHADOW, 2, 2, 4 'DWMAPI

'Determine Margins
With MARGINS
    .rightWidth = 1
    .leftWidth = 1
    .topHeight = 1
    .bottomHeight = 1
End With

DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea UFSHADOW, MARGINS 'DWMAPI

'Resize
frm.Width = frm.Width - 1
frm.Height = frm.Height - 1

End Sub
```

The issue is that on certain clients, this will compile fine, but the result will not be displayed when the userform is initialized. I believe this is because on some clients, the windows setting "Enable Desktop Composition" is disabled by default and unable to be modified. A workaround I plan on using is to test whether or not Desktop Composition is enabled and if it is not, I will not call the sub.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to test this. In the remarks section of this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969524(v=vs.85).aspx describes what should be returned if the `DwmSetWindowAttribute` function fails: `DWM_E_COMPOSITIONDISABLED`. I have tried setting this function equal to a few variable types, but it will not work.

Examples:

Desktop Composition Disabled
[image: No Shadow Visible]
Desktop Composition Enabled

[image: Shadow Visible]

Any Suggestions? Thanks

Edit: In response to Mat's Mug's questions:
No error is thrown, it simply just does not draw the shadow.

You probably did not get the intended result as there are a few other API functions I call in relation to the "Add Shadow" sub which turn of the window caption and another which turns off the border. I can post those as well, but would make this post quite long.

I am a bit new to using windows API functions, I don't quite know your comments on the IF conditionals and VB Signatures, but I am researching it now..

As far as the bitness go, it's very likely that this tool will be accessed on both 32 and 64 bit OS. update.. I have just tested on both versions, my local machine has 64bit OS, the problem version has 32bit

Comment: Does it throw any error if the setting is disabled? FWIW all I'm getting is a white border around the client area (Win7 Pro x64, 32-bit Office 2010)... is that the intended effect? Would be nice to include screenshots of "expected vs actual". Also you should wrap the `Declare` functions in `#If` conditional compilation blocks, and provide VBA6 *and* VBA7 signatures.. are all clients using the same version & bitness?

Comment: @mats-mug, I have updated the OP with some additional information

Comment: If you're just not going to call it if the setting is disabled, what difference does it make, since the code doesn't error?

Comment: Hi Rory, I would like to draw a border in the case that is disabled. I don't think the totally flat version clearly identifies the area as a userform.